# How to handle a server error with ADODB on AppEngine? Is ADODB supported on AppEngine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, activerecord

I'm trying to port a PHP application to the Preview of PHP support on AppEngine with a CloudSQL instance as database.

This application is open source, and uses ADODB for accessing it's database:

see: http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

There is a single point where it tries to include ADODB :

```
require_once($rootpath."adodb/adodb-errorpear.inc.php");
require_once($rootpath."adodb/adodb.inc.php");
$db = NewADOConnection($db_dsn);
```

Now I downloaded and included the latest version of ADODB. It's now in the root of the project (folder adodb, as in the file above).

When I deploy to AppEngine, I get this response :

```
GET http://resolute-radar-508.appspot.com/


Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

and the log of appengine gives me this Error 204:

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
>   causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used
>   for the next request to your application.

How to handle this server error with ADODB on AppEngine? Is ADODB supported on AppEngine ?

Comment: A 204 means that the runtime exited unexpectedly, most likely due to a bug in the runtime. We'll need to take a look and see what might be causing this to happen.